# Update a SharePoint user field to only accept people - Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I'm adding a field to an existing list by doing...

```
$spList.Fields.Add(
    "SourceManager",
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::User,
    $false
)

$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Indexed = $true;
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].EnforceUniqueValues = $true;
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Required = $true;
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Update();
```

This is fine, but I also want to set the field to only allow people (not people  & groups as is the default behavior here). I can't find the setting.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set the selection mode for the field prior to updating. The two options are presented below:

```
$spList.Fields.Add(
    "SourceManager",
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::User,
    $false
)

$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Indexed = $true;
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].EnforceUniqueValues = $true;
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Required = $true;

$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].SelectionMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserSelectionMode]::PeopleAndGroups; # For people and groups.
$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].SelectionMode = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserSelectionMode]::PeopleOnly; # For people only.


$spList.Fields["SourceManager"].Update();
```